# In bash, find all files that end with a certain extension and delete the parent folders and all its contents

Tags: bash, sh

How can I find all files that end w/ a certain extension (.exe) and delete the parent folder

Comment: @RedX: Maybe without the `..`. The parent folder of a file is not the parent folder of its folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove any folder containing a .exe file, you can use something like this :

```
sudo find / -name '*.exe' -exec sh -c 'rm -rf $(dirname $0)' {} \;
```

Here, you apply `sh -c 'rm -rf $(dirname $0)' {}` to every file found.

- `sh -c` indicates the following command will be interpretated with `/bin/sh`, the `-c` flag that the arguments to this command will be passed inline
- `rm -rf $(dirname $0)` is the command to remove the parent folder (provided by `dirname`) of the 1st argument provided.
- `{}` is the argument provided to your command. It is specific to `find` and contains the full path of every match

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` and `rm`, something like:

```
for f in $(find /root/dir -type f -name \*.exe); do
    rm -rf ${f%/*}
done
```